# opencv- ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' in Spyder python prompt

Tags: python, import, spyder, opencv

I have installed `opencv` package and the statement `import cv2` is working fine when I run it in the python prompt but the same `import cv2` is giving `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2'`, when I run it in the spyder prompt.

[python prompt in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKahA.jpg)

[python prompt in spyder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lCO3p.jpg)

Thanking you -P.Janardhan.

Comment: are you using same python version in both pics ?

Comment: yeah, i got the what's the problem is, Thank you. in command prompt -python-3.6.2 at - C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe and in spyder prompt- python-3.6.5 at -C:\Users\WELCOME\Anaconda3\python.exe. And now i changed the python interpreter path from default to C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe in spyder but getting "An error ocurred while starting the kernel Your Python environment or installation doesn't have the ipykernel and cloudpickle modules installed on it. Without these modules is not possible for Spyder to create a console for you." while launching spyder. How to resolve this.